# Bootstrap carousel-indicators (28 indicators) on 2 lines

Tags: css, carousel, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 carousel which having 28 pictures. The indicators on Small and medium devices, the indicators not breaking lines (some indicators are lost somewhere). It does not breaking line break.

How can i acheiving this?

```
.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 15;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    list-style: none;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

On small devices, only few indicators are visible.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 554px) {
            .carousel-indicators {
                display: table !important;
                line-height: 15px !important;
                margin-left: 18% !important;
            }
        }
@media screen and (min-width: 555px) and (max-width: 767px) {
            .carousel-indicators {
                display: table !important;
                line-height: 15px !important;
                margin-left: 18% !important;

            }
        }
```